# How to stop a value from returning 'None'?

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I was trying to do one of the practice projects from the book I am learning python from and I am stuck on the second bit of the exercise where I should write a code that adds a list to a dictionary.

for that I was trying to write the following code:

```
 def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for a in addedItems:
                   if a not in inventory:
                       inventory.setdefault(a, 1)

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```

However, after the last for loop inventory will return none as it has reached the end of the list but that will cause inv to be None and it returns an error.

I was thinking, that I could just stop the code when the returned value is none, I tried to write an elif statement but it wasn't working.

Any ideas how to do that?

P.S: Even if it's obvious please do not post a complete code for the above, I would like to do it myself, I am only looking for an answer for this question :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `inv` is set to `None` because **in python all functions that do not explicitly `return` a value implicitly `return None`**.

The way you defined `addToInventory`, it will modify `inv` implicitly (beware of this kind of side-effects, sometimes this is really not what you want or expect).

An alternative to replacing `inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)` with just the function call is to make `addToInventory` explicitly `return inventory`. It's up to you to decide which style you prefer.

#### Fix:

I know you asked not to give full-code solutions, but from your comments this is the only way I can explain it clearly enough.
As we discussed in the comments, you need to add an explicit `return` if the rest of the code is given by the exercise's framework. What is important, however, is *where* you put that statement. In python, white space matters. If you put the return in line with `inventory.setdefault`, it will be executed during the first iteration of the loop. To have it run through the loop and then return, the `return` needs to be **on the same indentation level as the for**:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for a in addedItems:
        if a not in inventory:
            inventory.setdefault(a, 1)
    return inventory #<<<<<<< IN LINE WITH THE FOR
```

Comment: The issue is with your and the above answer is that I was supposed to only fill out the code under the def.

Comment: def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    # your code goes here

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)

Comment: Then you missed the `return inventory` statement :) What you're doing now is actually updating the `inv`, but then you throw it away and overwrite it with the return value of the function, which **by default** is `None`.

Comment: So I have added the return inventory under the inventory.setdefault statement, however then it only added the first value of the list that the dictionary does not contain (dagger).

Comment: Makes sense, sorry if I made you pull your hair out :).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be reassigning `inv` to the return value of that function. It will be changed in-place. Just do:

```
addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```

Comment: It works the way you said but as I mentioned under GPhilo's answer, I wasn't supposed tot ouch that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return anything, hence inv is None

But what Daniel said will solve the issue as well ;-)

Comment: Which I am aware of, as mentioned above, but I have checked the step-by-step breakdown and before none it assigns "ruby" and "dagger" nicely, so if I stopped it before it returns none it should work.

Comment: It works at the point of stopping since at that time inv is still valid. But since the function does not return anything, you assign None at the line inv = addToInventory( ...) when the function returns.

Comment: @K.Robert see my answer as for why `inv` is set to None